# how to set multiple Content Security Policies in a chrome extension manifest.json file

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, manifest, manifest.json

in the [Google chrome documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) I found that I can add content Security Policy to allow an external javascript file to work on my extension.

but I couldn't find how to add multiple ones. Is it an array of Strings?

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://example.com; object-src 'self'"
```

I tried to put multiple lines like that but it doesn't work. Goes error:

Refused to load the script https://example.com because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https://example.com". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSP policy is a single string (containing a semicolon-separated list of *directives* and their arguments). It applies to all extension pages.

If you need a single policy with multiple sources, you can do that. In fact, you already have that: `'self'` and `https://example.com` are two sources.

Read about CSP in general and `script-src` directive, e.g. [on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src).

> ## Syntax
>
> One or more sources can be allowed for the `script-src` policy:
>
> ```
> Content-Security-Policy: script-src <source>;
> Content-Security-Policy: script-src <source> <source>;
> ```

So you just need to space-separate them between `script-src` and the semicolon.

Make sure that your sources *do not contain paths.*
E.g. `https://example.com` is OK, but `https://example.com/` or `https://example.com/script.js` are not.

If you need multiple independent policies for different pages, I'm afraid you can't do that.